# Garden hose turns but does not unscrew

Tags: hose

Hi the previous owners of my mobile home left a garden hose attached to the outside and i cannot get it off. It turns but isn't coming off[image]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to turn the hose instead of the connector.
If you can't get the connector (brighter silver) to move by hand, you might need some big pliers or channel locks to get it to move.

Comment: Agree with @Ben. If it give you a hard time with a wrench, it might not hurt to spray a little pb blaster or liquid wrench on top, where the shiny metal meets the dull grey metal of the spigot and let it sit for an hour.

Comment: Is that a male hose fitting on a female hose bib? Kinda backwards but that’s what it looks like to me. You may need to hold the hose with pliers and turn the fitting to loosen it up.

Comment: I’d cut the hose off instead of holding it; it’s trashed. Then channel lock it to open

Comment: Ed Beal, that's how I interpret that too. Weird. It might be that the hose bib had what's called a "vacuum breaker" installed on it, and the previous homeowner couldn't figure out what it was, then broke it trying to remove it and had to rig up something to make it work. Those vacuum breaker bibs are required where I live, they are a royal pain and they are designed to not come off. I had to drill out a set-pin to do it ;-)

Comment: Thank you is there a certain size i need for channel lock pliers, first time owning a home sorry if that's a dumb question. Also if i get that stupid bolt thing off do i need to replace it?